# Loading image to picture box from panel image gallary

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I created a image gallery in windows forms application using adding multiple images to into a panel. Now I want to load the clicked image in to another picture box. Is there any one can help me?

My Code

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
ofd.Filter = "JPG|*.jpg|JPEG|*.jpeg|PNG|*.png";
ofd.Multiselect = true;
DialogResult dr = ofd.ShowDialog();
if(dr==DialogResult.OK)
{
    int x = 20;
    int y = 20;
    int maxHeight = -1;
    string[] files = ofd.FileNames;
    foreach (string img in files)
    {
        PictureBox pic = new PictureBox();
        pic.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(img);
        pic.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        pic.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
        x += pic.Width + 10;
        maxHeight = Math.Max(pic.Height, maxHeight);
        if(x > this.pnlGallary.Width - 100)
        {
            x = 20;
            y += maxHeight + 10;
        }
        this.pnlGallary.Controls.Add(pic);
    }
}
```

[Sample Image is Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geKf5.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please replace your code look like below:

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
ofd.Filter = "JPG|*.jpg|JPEG|*.jpeg|PNG|*.png";
ofd.Multiselect = true;
DialogResult dr = ofd.ShowDialog();
if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
{
    int x = 20;
    int y = 20;
    int maxHeight = -1;
    string[] files = ofd.FileNames;
    foreach (string img in files)
    {
        PictureBox pic = new PictureBox();
        pic.Click += new EventHandler(pictureBox_Click);  // call the custom event for dynamic generated PictureBox
        pic.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(img);
        pic.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        pic.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
        x += pic.Width + 10;
        maxHeight = Math.Max(pic.Height, maxHeight);
        if (x > this.pnlGallary.Width - 100)
        {
            x = 20;
            y += maxHeight + 10;
        }
        this.pnlGallary.Controls.Add(pic);
    }
}
```

And add common click event handler for dynamic generated `PictureBox` as below

```
void pictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Image = ((PictureBox)sender).Image;
}
```